# Is there a framework availabe that will let me load all the tweets of a user?

Tags: java, linux, windows, twitter

Is there any way, I can download or see all the tweets for any user ? I want to see the oldest tweets for some users when they have 8K tweets. Browsing down for the first one will take very long !

If there is any shell command for it or twitter-api available for the task ?

Comment: You can look Twitter4j, java-twitter, jtwitter. The best one for me is Twitter4j.

Answer (score 0):

At most, you can get the last 3,200 tweets.  You can retrieve up to 200 per request.

See the documentation at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline